# Why am I getting missingmethodException for file.length() function?

Tags: file, groovy

How to find size of a file which is received via Restful web-service media as Multi-part in groovy?

I am trying to find a size of file which is going to be uploaded using a API using multipart/formdata.

```
methods = ['create']
representation {
    mediaTypes = [
       "application/vnd.hedtech.v1+json", 
       "application/json" ,
       "multipart/form-data"
    ]
```

I did try to find a size of the same file using file.length() but getting error.

Note: After upload I can easily find out the size of a same file. But My requirement is to check file size before upload. How can I do that?

Comment: _"but getting error."_ what error?

Comment: missingmethod exception. but I remove line file.length() then that error disappears

Comment: Where is that in your coffee? I can't see it in the question?

Comment: Edited my coffee. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file.getSize() works for file is multi-part transfer. Returns the size in bytes